# How to redirect after summit form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

because react-router v4 can't use 'browserHistory' then what should i do? if i want go to next page after summit form. here is my code

```
let Profile = ({ history, handleSubmit }) => {
return (
    <FirstSec>
        <div>
            <p>Profile</p>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)} >
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Field name="firstName" type="text" className="form-control" label="first name" component={renderField} />
                    <Field name="lastName" type="text" className="form-control" label="last name" component={renderField} />
                    <Field name="tel" type="tel" className="form-control" label="tel" component={renderField} />
                    <Field name="email" type="email" className="form-control" label="email" component={renderField} />
                </div>

                <button onClick={() => history.push('/apply/1/Occupation')}>Back</button>
                <button type="submit">Next</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </FirstSec>
);
```

};

```
    Profile = reduxForm({
    form: 'profile'
    })(Profile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [React-redux-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) for it.